# XMLSerializer to XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, serialization

I have been working with XML in database LINQ and find that it is very difficult to work with the serializer.

The database LINQ required a field that store `XElement`.

I have a complex object with many customized structure class, so I would like to use the XmlSerializer to serialize the object.

However, the serializer can only serialize to file ("C:\xxx\xxx.xml") or a memory stream.

However to convert or serialize it to be a XElement so that I can store in the database using LINQ?

And How to do the reverse? i.e. Deserialize an XElement...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use this

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, value);
    stream.Position = 0;

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        XElement element = XElement.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

deserialize :

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XElement));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     xs.Serialize(ms, xml);
     ms.Position = 0;

     xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourType));
     object obj = xs.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems like it should be easier than it is.

Comment: While this would work, the answer by @Timothy is much better.

Answer (score 12):

To make what John Saunders was describing more explicit, deserialization is very straightforward:

```
public static object DeserializeFromXElement(XElement element, Type t)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = element.CreateReader())
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t);
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Serialization is a little messier because calling `CreateWriter()` from an XElement or XDocument creates child elements. (In addition, the XmlWriter created from an XElement has ConformanceLevel.Fragment, which causes XmlSerialize to fail unless you use the workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19047355/2946652).)  As a result, I use an XDocument, since this requires a single element, and gets us around the XmlWriter issue:

```
public static XElement SerializeToXElement(object o)
{
    var doc = new XDocument();
    using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter())
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, o);
    }

    return doc.Root;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, see [Serialize Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize.aspx) to see that the serializer can handle alot more than just memory streams or files.

Second, try using XElement.CreateWriter and then passing the resulting XmlWriter to the serializer.

Comment: XElement.CreateWriter does not seem to be available

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.createwriter.aspx.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I must be looking at the wrong class. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

The SQL has XML data type may be this can help you look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx)

Comment: How will that help with serialization or XElement?